# Modifying queries on the fly depending on selected filters

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sharding, database-partitioning

In an existing codebase some tables are now horizontally sharded within the same database but in different namespaces.

E.g. let's say there previously was a large table `users` which is now sharded by the country field so there are now the following tables: `us.users`, `ca.users`, `es.users` etc.

Since every single query to the tables already contains the `country` filter I was thinking of the following minimalistic adjustment so that there's no need to subclass the original model for every country manually or dynamically:

```py
class SessionWithShardedTableSupport(Session):
    """ Use sharded tables on the fly """

    def connection(self, mapper=None, clause=None, bind=None, close_with_result=None, **kw):
        if mapper and mapper.local_table.name == 'users':
            mapper.local_table.schema = '???' # `us` or `ca` or `es`

        return super().connection(mapper, clause, bind, close_with_result, **kw)
```

The solution would work fine if there was a way to get the `country` filter from the query from within the session but there doesn't seem any (at least inspecting both `mapper` & `clause` parameters didn't reveal them).

1) Is there a way to get the where clause / the filters from within the session?

2) Is there maybe a better way to adjust the table name / table namespace on the fly with minimalistic changes to the existing code?

Comment: Why not use the built-in partitioning in postgres?

Comment: @Jeremy good question, not sure if Google's managed "Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL 9.6" allows for that + unfortunately I don't have much control over this breaking change anyway.

Comment: Ah, ok.  You may be able to use sqlalchemy's multi-tenancy support: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/11/changelog/migration_11.html#multi-tenancy-schema-translation-for-table-objects